# Normalizing the Paths in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, path

I am trying to normalize the paths in `NodeJS`, so that irrespective of user input `(*nix/windows)`, the path should be accessible by `node path`.

```
Ex: c:/test/test.xml
    c:\\test\test.xml
    c:\test/test.xml
    /usr/var/test.xml
    /usr/var\test.xml
```

These should be normalized so that `path` lib can access them. I tried using `path.normalize` on the input `/usr/var\test.xml`, it didn't work. the output path string is same as input instead of `/usr/var/test.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written myself simple function to achieve this

```
export function pathToNix(pathStr: string) {
     var p = path.normalize(pathStr);
     var path_regex = /\/\//;
     p = p.replace(/\\/g, "/");
     while (p.match(path_regex)) {
         p = p.replace(path_regex, "/");
     }
     return p;
}
```

To clarify few things - Windows supports *nix type file structure (c:/test/a.txt). Thus converted all paths to *nix format.